# transformed values return NaN in some cases but numbers in others

Tags: r, nan, transformation

I've run into a very bizarre issue in my `R` coding. Here is a sample of some values I have and the results if I take the values to 1/10. Note how each becomes NaN.

```r
vals <- c(-0.02964166, -0.01018776, -0.01758487)
vals^(1/10)

[1] NaN NaN NaN
```

But if I take the numbers individually to the 1/10, I don't get `NaN`s but values instead.

```r
-0.02964166^(1/10)

[1] -0.7033804

-0.01018776^(1/10)

[1] -0.6321321

-0.01758487^(1/10)

[1] -0.6675963
```

What's going on here and how can I perform this operation on the vector so that I don't lose the numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a variation of [R FAQ 7.33](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-are-powers-of-negative-numbers-wrong_003f), and has to do with the precedence of the *unary minus* operator: -0.1^0.1 (for example) is parsed as -(0.1^0.1). When you put the expression into a vector, the `-` is evaluated *before* the `^`.

```r
sign(vals)*(abs(vals))^(1/10)
```

Being very pedantic, you can get *one* of the complex roots this way:

```r
as.complex(vals)^(1/10)
[1] 0.6689545+0.2173565i 0.6011934+0.1953396i 0.6349218+0.2062986i
```

or *all* of the roots this way

```r
polyroot(c(-vals[1], rep(0,9), 1))
 [1]  0.4134366+0.5690467i -0.4134366+0.5690467i -0.4134366-0.5690467i
 [4]  0.6689545-0.2173565i  0.0000000+0.7033804i -0.6689545+0.2173565i
 [7]  0.0000000-0.7033804i  0.6689545+0.2173565i -0.6689545-0.2173565i
[10]  0.4134366-0.5690467i
```

(this finds the roots of the equation `1*x^10 + 0*x^9 + ... + 0*x - val == 0`, i.e. `x^10 - val = 0`)

Technically, I think (unless I get something wrong) that the actual root you're looking for is the fifth one (`0.0000000+0.7033804i`); this is off by a factor of `i` relative to the `sign(x)*(abs(x)^(1/10))` answer ... we can confirm that the answer *should* be pure-imaginary, i.e.

```r
all.equal((0.7033804i)^10, as.complex(vals[1]), tol = 1e-6)
```

is TRUE.

Comment: you can also rewrite your calculation as: `x^{\frac{1}{10}} = \sqrt[10]{x^1}`; as Ben said the minus is evaluated before the `^` and hence R tries to calculate the square root of a negative number which do not have real square roots, hence the `NaN` result.